# Javascript: merge 2 arrays (different properties)

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, lodash

I have a tough requirement needed your advises.

I have 2 arrays:

```
var array1 = [{ 'x': 1, 'z': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'z': 1 }];
var array2 = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 3 }];
```

Requirement: merge 2 array into one with format:

```
[{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 3 , 'z': 1 }]
```

I have gone through [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10) library, features like 'merge' or 'union' don't serve for this purpose.

Any solutions are welcomed and appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like a homework task to me...

Comment: My point is for the large array, about 10000 items. I can use loop logic to achieve it, but if any best practice, please share it.

Comment: Seems to me as though you should just use a simple loop. I see no other way from what libraries I'm familiar with. For that matter, if there are any libraries for the task, they'll just use loops too.

Comment: @francophong nobody here is engaging in hate speech (I guess it's not the word you actually meant to use, as you don't seem to be a native English speaker (EDIT: just an assumption, I see you're from the UK but your name suggested otherwise. if that's not the case it's even worse :P)). The other users just pointed out it looked like homework and suggested to just use a loop.

Comment: Thanks for comments @Federico

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var array1 = [{ 'x': 1, 'z': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'z': 1 }];
var array2 = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 3 }];

let result = array1.map((o,i) => ({...o, ...array2[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for new objects.

```js
var array1 = [{ 'x': 1, 'z': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'z': 1 }],
    array2 = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 3 }],
    result = array1.map((o,i) => Object.assign(o, array2[i]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```